# Problem when running babel

Tags: miktex, babel, hebrew

I am using `babel` installation (used Miktex 2.9 package manager to install) and the Culmus MiKTeX package (retrieved from http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/culmusmiktex.html)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document}
שלום
\end{document}
```

When running the code I get the following error (shown in the `.log` file)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.3.5)  5 MAR 2014 15:14
entering extended mode
**letter.tex
(<file path omitted>
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2013/12/03 3.9h The Babel package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\switch.def"
File: switch.def 2008/07/08 v3.8m Babel language switching mechanism
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\english.ldf"
Language: english 2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
.... last line repeated hundreds of times
```

Looking at the `.log` it seems that Hebrew is not one of the supported languages. However, removing the `hebrew` option (e.g. `\usepackage[english]{babel}` has the same output).

What's going on here?

Comment: ps adding the \selectlanguage{hebrew} and \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} did not help

Comment: Hm. Well babel.sty and switch.def have different versions and this is problably the problem. But where did you get babel.sty version 3.9h from? I still have v3.8m and there is not update open.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I wonder, too. Especially we can see above the `pdftex` message that “Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns” is loaded.

Comment: Since you have a newer babel installation, but a format file with an older babel, try to regenerate the formats.